# Loosing old aggregated records after adding repartitioning in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I had a Kafka stream with following operations:
stream.mapValues.groupByKey.aggregate. Aggregation is adding records into the list basically.
Now I changed implementation to that:
stream.flatMap.groupByKey.aggregate. FlatMap is duplicating record: first record is exactly the same like in old implementation and second one has key changed. So after the change of implementation repartitioning is happening, while before, it wasn't (and it's fine). My problem is that after releasing the change, old aggregated records for old key disappeared. From the moment of change everything works as it should, but I don't understand this behaviour. As I understand, as I did not change the key, it should land on the same partition as previously and aggregation should continue adding messages to old list, not starting from beginning. Could anyone help me understand why it's happening?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

If you change your processing topology, in general, you need to reset your application and reprocess all data from the input topic to recompute the state.

In your case, I assume that the `aggregation` operator has a different name after the change and thus, does not "find" its local state and changelog topic any longer.

You can compare the names for both topologies via `Topology#describe()`.

To allow for a smooth upgrade, you would need to provide a fixed name for `aggregate()` via `Materialized.as(...)`. If you provide a fixed name (ie, same in old and new topology) the issue would go away. However, because your original topology did not provide a fixed name, it's hard to get out of the situation.